# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la información del inicio de sesión?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un proyecto, y en una parte me gustaría que una vez iniciada la sesión, apareciera el nombre del usuario.
Mi verificador del login es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../conexion.php";
$re=mysqli_query($con,"select * from usuarios where user='".$_POST['user']."' AND 
                    password='".$_POST['password']."'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
        $arreglo[]=array('nombre'=>$f['nombre']);
    }
    if(isset($arreglo)){
        $_SESSION['user']=$arreglo;
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: login.php?error=datos no validos");
    }
?>
```

Mi pagina de login es:

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_GET['error'])){
            echo '<span class="alert"><center>Datos No Validos</center></span>';
        }
        ?>

        <form class="contacto" action="verificar.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <label>Usuario: <span>*</span>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required>
            </label>

            <label>Contraseña: <span>*</span>
                <input type="passwprd" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"  required>
            </label>

            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesion" class="boton boton-verde">

        </form>
```

y por si acaso mi conexión es esta:

```
<?php
    $server="localhost";
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $db='noticias';
    $con=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password)or die("No se ha podido establecer la conexion");
    $sdb=mysqli_select_db($con,$db)or die("La base de datos no existe");
?>
```

Intente varios métodos, pero no logro como hacerlo, quiero que diga algo como : Hola (nombre del usuario), este mensaje saldrá en un archivo llamado admin

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Al inciar sesión de manera correcta, debes setear las variables de SESSION que quieras usar. Ahora mismo veo que usas un `$arreglo`, por lo que creo que guardas toda la info dentro no ?

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre actualmente en tu código?

Comment: Excorpio, si guardo toda la información del SESISION en un `$arreglo`, y este arreglo solo incluye el nombre del usuario, que es lo que quiero que se muestre

Comment: A. Cadano, el inicio de sesión funciona correctamente, solo que quiero que en cierta pagina me muestre el nombre del usuario que esta logeado

Comment: Si imprimo `$SESSION["user"]` sale lo siguiente:

`array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["nombre"]=> string(23) "Jose Angel Colin Najera" } }`

Como puedo hacer que solo muestre el nombre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

Los datos de mi sesión estaban guardadas en `$arreglo` y esta variable estaba dentro de `$SESSION["user"]`
Mandar a imprimir $SESSION["user"]:

```
include "conexion";
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
```

Me salía lo siguiente:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["nombre"]=> string(23) "Jose Angel Colin Najera" } }
```

Con eso me doy cuenta que los datos de `$arreglo`  que es un array están dentro de `$SESSIOn["user"]` que es otro array.

Entonces primero saco el `$arreglo` de `$SESSION["user"]` de la siguiente manera:

```
$datos= $_SESSION['user'][0];
var_dump($datos["nombre"]); #Poniendo la key que quiero buscar
```

y eso me arroja:

```
string(23) "Jose Angel Colin Najera"
```

Ya con eso solo es cuestion de imprimirla y listo:

```
print($datos["nombre"]);
```

Comment: Buenas, recién veo esto. Si estás guardando solo 1 dato, no es necesario el arreglo. Podrías crear solo el SESSION["nombre"] y guardar solo el nombre como quieres. Un arreglo es para más datos, en conjunto. Si quieres nombre, id y correo por ejemplo, guardas, eso mismo, nombre, id y correo. Luego los rescatas